# How to find whether Current TD is last TD in TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a single row and multiple `<td>`s in it. In one of my functions I come across a situation where I have to find out whether my `currentSelectedTD` is the last `<td>` in the row so that I can treat it diffrently.

I tried `$(currentSelectedTD).is(":last")` which is not working and always returns `true`.
I have also tried couple of other possibilities which are not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some more of your code? A single jQuery selector (that you said didn't work) is hardly useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use .next() to check if the element has the immediately following sibling.

```
if( $(currentSelectedTD).next().length == 0) {
    // is last 
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked wonderfully.. But 1 problem. Though there were multiple TD's present ahead I always got length as "1". And in case of last TD it returned length "0". And thats why it worked for me. Could you please explain it further.

Comment: `.length == 0` is the standard jQuery way of testing whether something exists.

Comment: .next always returns the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements (only 1 node), therefore for each td which is not the last .next().length will always be 1, unless $(currentSelectedTD) matches more than 1 node, of course.

Comment: @Corneliu - ohh.. I should have got that on myself. Somehow i was expecting it to return me length of next present tds. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for this quite easily, and without tapping into jQuery:

```
var isLastChild = currentSelectedTD.parentNode.lastElementChild == currentSelectedTD;
```

This has the advantage of being both native DOM and simple, however it would only work on a  modern browser (e.g. needs IE9). You can tweak it to work with anything, but then it wouldn't be an one-liner.

Comment: @GirishK: There was an error in it. I corrected it, but probably the solution you accepted is a more practical approach.

Comment: Yaa.. But soemone who doesnt want to use jQuery would be helped by your piece of code.

Comment: Also: `isLast = --td.parentNode.cells.length == td.cellIndex;`. Works in all browsers, even IE 6.

Answer (score 0):

Think you should do `:last` filter on the full set and store the result in a variable. 
Then do a loop through the set and compare each one with the one you stored.

Answer (score 0):

use-

```
if($('.currentSelectedTD:last')){
//do what ever you want
}
```

or

```
$lastTd = $('.currentSelectedTD').parent('tr').find('td:last')
```

Comment: Your first example returns a jQuery object which always passes `if`.

Comment: Yes, same thing is happening in my case. Didnt try second though.
" if( $(currentSelectedTD).next().length == 0) " worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use:

```
$(currentSelectedTD).is("td:last");
```