# jQuery and XML: Is this the last element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have grabbed some `XML` data using this piece of jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "siteList.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('wrapper').each(function(){
            $(this).find('site').each(function(){
                //check whether this is the last element...
            });
        });
    }
});
```

What I would like to do is:
Check whether I am parsing the last `site` element from the `XML` I pulled in.

**edit:**
I cannot (as far as I'm aware), do this:

```
$(this).find('site').each(function(){
    $(this).last(); //nope
    $(this).find('site').last(); //nope
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how do I check if an element is the last sibling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681581/jquery-how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-the-last-sibling)

Comment: Not a duplicate - this is about XML not Markup

Comment: So? DOM is DOM. Whether you built it from XML or HTML does not matter (at least for traversal). I mean, you are also using `.find` here. Why should it be different for other functions?

Comment: @Neurofluxation: What does the "M" in XML stand for?

Comment: *I cannot (as far as I'm aware), do this*... right, because the way you use `.last` here does not make sense. `$(this).last()` will be the same as `$(this)` as only one element is selected (`this`). As long as `site`'s are not nested, `$(this).find('site')` will return an empty set.

Comment: Well, you get the last element before the `each` loop: `var last = $(this).find('site').get(-1);` (same as `$(this).find('site').last().get(0)`) and then compare it inside the the callback against `this`. Maybe you like this duplicate better: [How to find whether Current TD is last TD in TR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705399/how-to-find-whether-current-td-is-last-td-in-tr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use something like this to get the last site:

```
$(this).find('site').last()
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ':last' selector or the .last() function. You could do a test to see if the current site is the same as the last one.